# Python and XML for a program

Tags: python, xml

I'm currently trying to write a program based on python to manage my farm later.
I want to store my data in a xml file.

The file structure should be something like:

```
<animals>
    <animal ID="AT-12-3456-789" Birthdate="21.5.2012" Sex="Male" Box=5 />
<animals/>
```

So my question is how to add/remove/modify an Animal?

As XML Parser I would like to use the built in xml.etree.ElementTree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
```

I completed the python course at codecademy, but I can't find a good example of this nowhere are, so I ask here and hope you guys can help me :)
Thanks

Comment: Just a comment on your XML structure: it is a really, really terrible idea to use the "AnimalNumber" as the element name. The element name should be something like "Animal", and the number should be an attribute just like Birthdate etc. The element name should be used to describe the _type_ of the element, not to carry data.

Comment: @l4mpi         
maybe youre right, but i think this way is better for searching a animal(for modify) or isnt it?

Comment: It's just as easy to search for an attribute. Your proposed way would make it impossible to write an XML scheme for the document, as you don't have a shared name between your elements. Not being able to write a scheme means you can't do validation and XML transforms or use tools like JAXB. Regarding examples for ElementTree, have you checked the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)? It includes examples of its use and specifically a section about modifying files...

Answer (score 1):

Try [Markup.py](http://markup.sourceforge.net/). You can use it to write both html and xml and it is easy to work with programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element to your XML file by

```
root = Element("animals") # root element. I assume its animals

root.append(Element("one"))
root.append(Element("two"))
root.append(Element("three"))
```

Modify multiple elements by using `Element.set('attribute-name', 'value')`
So if I wanted to change *Box* value of one tag I would use `element.set('Box', 6)`

To remove we use `Element.remove()`

I do recommend you use minidom(xml.dom.minidom) instead; I find it much easier to use. 
Also I recommend you follow a better XML schema, check out the [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/)